# Two screens in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, graphics, multiple-monitors

Users,

at work I'm using Ubuntu now for a while.
I always try to keep the system up-to-date, so I also made the upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 in October this year.
In 12.04, I had some trouble making the two screens I have in front of me display the right things in a proper way. After upgrading, Ubuntu 12.10 shot my screens! The bigger one with the better resolution was just mirrored from the low-res, smaller screen, so as a matter of fact they were useless. I went to the settings and tried to fix it, but as my system doesn't have any graphics-hardware (remember, it's a simple workstation), it said that this was to large of a desktop and I should switch to the good-old 2D-GUI they used to have. BUT: it isn't there! after a short time of research I found out that they didn't keep the old 2D-Layout. And the 3D one is a troublemaker for small systems with no graphic card.

Is there any possibility to fix this problem, to reactivate the old GUI? I don't want to downgrade again 'cause I like being up-to-date, but if keeping 12.10 means working with one screen, I will have to get back.

I hope anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance,

Dave

P.S.: If you're missing any information, let me know what it is, I'll be glad to provide them as soon as I can!

typed `lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2` to the terminal and it answered:

```
VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV370 5B60 [Radeon X300 (PCIE)] [1002:5b60]
Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device [1002:0402]
Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Comment: If your system has graphics, then it has a graphics card, be it a physically replaceable card, or internal graphics on the motherboard, or on the CPU. You should specify what CPU and graphics driver are being used on the system in question, so people can better help you.

Comment: If you don't know what graphics card you've got, just use the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2`

Comment: just copied your command to the terminal, and it answered:   VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV370 5B60 [Radeon X300 (PCIE)] [1002:5b60]
 Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device [1002:0402]
 Kernel driver in use: radeon

Comment: Same problem here, any solutions?

Comment: what a pitty nobody can really provide help in this kind of forums... in 4/5 cases I have to provide the answer myself after finding it somewhere hidden very well. In this case I didn't find an answer, so i still have one switched-off-monitor on my desk. Thank you for the massive help!